# Double quotes in Oracle Alias

Tags: oracle, double, alias, quotes

I am having fickle of problem in Oracle 9i

select 1"FirstColumn" from dual;

Oracle throwing error while executing above query. ORA-03001: unimplemented feature in my Production server.

The Same query is working fine in my Validation server. Both servers are with Oracle 9i

Any one have Idea what's wrong...? Is this something configurable item in Oracle server.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
 SELECT 1 AS "'FirstColumn'" FROM dual;
```

There is a similar question:
[Double Quotes in Oracle Column Aliases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56591/double-quotes-in-oracle-column-aliases)

Answer (score 1):

What is the full Oracle version on both servers?  9i is a marketing label-- are you comparing a 9.0.1.x database to a 9.2.0.x database?

Answer (score 1):

Does it give the same output if you do?

```
select 1 as "FirstColumn" from dual;
```

To find out the specific versions on yoru Validation and Production servers, do this SQL on each and compare the results:

```
select * from v$version;
```

Answer (score 0):

The below are the versions of my server:

Oracle9i Enterprise Edition Release 9.2.0.8.0 - Validation
Oracle9i Enterprise Edition Release 9.2.0.8.0 - 64bit Production

64 bit does make a difference. SELECT 1 AS "'FirstColumn'" FROM dual; is working but will leads me to update nearly hundreds of packages. Configuration change could be handy rather changing the code.

Regards,
Hanumath

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I have it working fine with me on 9.2.0.7:

```
select 1"FirstColumn" from dual
```

Feels like a bug to me; have you tried Metalink?

Answer (score 0):

Hanumath: MetaLink is Oracle's support service. If you're Oracle is licensed, and with a support contract, you would have a MetaLink ID.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you should have a space between the 1 and the "FirstColumn"

```
SELECT 1 "FirstColumn" from dual;
```

That said, it's more correct to use the AS keyword the previous answerers indicated.

Comment: You don't *need* the space - works just fine without it. It is more readable with it though.