# Using OracleCommand with a column alias

Tags: .net, oracle10g, oraclecommand

I am attempting to write an oracle query that the client has requested a specific column name for the output.  Simple enough, I write the query using an [oracle column alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56591/double-quotes-in-oracle-column-aliases) using double quotes.  (Note that I am using the quotes because it just so happens that the requested column name is a reserved word.)
The issue is that I am receiving the from the error `ORA-00911: invalid character` when I attempt to execute the query using the following code:

```
OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(sqlquery, connection.Conn);
dt.Load(command.ExecuteReader());
```

I have tried the [oracle quote operator](http://www.memosoup.com/20110111/oracle-quote-and-quote-operator.html) and the various iterations of the [c# string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928909/in-c-can-i-escape-a-double-quote-in-a-literal-string) (i.e. @"this is ""testing"" the literal" and "this is \"testing\" the literal").

The query is simple in that I would like to do this:

```
select column1 as "alias1" from dual;
```

This works when I run it directly in Oracle but I am unable to get it to run via the .Net application.  Having escaped the double quotes and viewing the query in the debugger shows that it has been formatted as:

```
select column1 as \"alias1\" from dual;
```

It seems ¿obvious? that the backslashes are causing the Oracle error but how do I get around this?

Answer (score 1):

Wow.  After nearly an hour I discovered something stupid.  Let this be a warning to the rest of you.  [Don't leave the semicolon in the string literal for your query](http://collecteddotnet.wordpress.com/2009/04/30/ora-00911-invalid-charactern/).

In other words this is fine ...

string query = @"select column1 as ""alias1"" from dual";

... but this is not ...

string query = @"select column1 as ""alias1"" from dual**`;`**";

Note the small addition of the **`;`** in the second example.

I hope this helps someone else save some time.